# GKE kubectl logs returns authorization error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

```
# kubectl logs --tail=100 -f jerry-proxy-****
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

The error above suddenly shows up. It was working fine last week.

Comment: Able to resolve this? I tried applying cluster role bindings as mentioned in one of the comment , still didnt solve it

Answer (score 1):

The cluster role system:kubelet-api-admin has been added during the upgrade, so you need to add cluster role binding for user kubelet-api for accessing logs via kubectl logs.

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubelet-api-admin
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: kubelet-api
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:kubelet-api-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

For more information refer to this [link](https://github.com/tilt-dev/tilt/issues/3547).

Comment: This only happened on an old cluster of mine. My recent clusters are working fine

Comment: Have you tried role binding in the old cluster?

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I am facing the same issue after upgrading eks from 1.21 to 1.24. I tried what you mentioned but still the same for me the error is while getting logs and error reads
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)